# Looking for reference of present continuous and simple past in story telling?

Tags: past-simple, present-continuous

The sentence being: After pulling the fisherman to safety, the groomsmen returned for more wedding photos on the jetty – this time in their underwear, dripping wet and a little battered and bruised.

I think it should say After **he was** pulling the fisherman to safety, the groomsmen returned for more wedding photos on the jetty.

I could not find any reference why you can leave out **he was**. My assumption is, that AFTER implies, that this is past also as the whole story happened in the past and therefore this could be to stress this part of the story.
Does anyone have some reference for me on this? Thank you.

Comment: You can't use 'he was' about the grooms**men** (plural)

Comment: "After pulling" is a gerund phrase. It is correct. [Participles and gerunds](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/participles-and-gerunds)

Comment: Putting aside the singular/plural issue, although ***he was pulling*** is in principle grammatically valid, it's not idiomatic, and would almost never be used in such contexts (we'd invariably say ***he [had] pulled***).

Comment: It's grammatical but makes no sense. If he was engaged in (busy) pulling someone to safety, he could not have simultaneously be doing something else, right? Also, do you mean: groomsman? Singular?

Answer (score 0):

"After" can be (at least) two different words grammatically.

It can be a preposition, introducing a noun phrase:

> After lunch
>
> After his graduation

and that noun phrase can be a non-finite clause with a gerund:

> after pulling the fisherman to safety"

It can also be a (subordinating) conjunction, introducing a finite clause:

> after I got home
>
> after they pulled the fishermen to safety.

There is not usually any difference in meaning. The form with the gerund is probably a little more formal.

Comment: After I was explaining the problem to him, I was playing tennis and then went home. I think the past continuous can be used with after but the OP's sentence makes no sense....